# Create a byte bitmask using values from an array

Tags: c, arrays, byte, bitmask

I have to create one Byte mask in C.
I have an array where:

myArray[0] - continous mask first bit index

myArray[1] - continous mask last bit index

Continous mask means bits with ones. The rest bits in the Byte are zeros.

Example: myArray[0]=1 and myArray[1]=2 so my Byte mask should be: 00000110

myArray values may differend so the mask differs. 
I will use this mask on another Byte (with and/or/xor operations) to archieve desired result.

Can you please provide me with simple C language code that creates such a mask?

Comment: It would make most sense to store the LSB in byte 0, regardless of endianess.

Comment: why do you need to have the confusing array here? Just have 2 variables: for example `msb_index` and `lsb_index`.

Comment: First step in my task is to execute some console program that outputs data similar to this: 

===================

pattern: [ 3; 6;-3]

pattern: [ 4; 6;-2]

pattern: [ 2; 3; 6]

pattern: [ 2; 7; 4]

===================

Then I have to create four byte masks. First column contains LSB and second column contain MSB. The last column contains count for cyclic bit shif (left or right depending on sign pos/neg). I decided to filter out those values and feed them into an array for future operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
((1 << (myArray[1] -myArray[0] +1)) -1) << myArray[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to first use the second number to set all bits up to that point, and then use the first number to clear the bits below.

```
unsigned char mask = ((1 << (myArray[1] + 1)) - 1) & ~((1 << myArray[0]) - 1)
```

Using the values from your example, `((1 << (myArray[1] + 1)) - 1)` is going to be `((1 << (2 + 1)) - 1)` which is `00000111`. The second half evaluates to `~((1 << 1) - 1)` which is `11111110`. The end result is thus `00000111 & 11111110` which is `00000110`.